# Indexing problem with Spring Data Elastic migration from 3.x to 4.x

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data, jhipster, spring-data-elasticsearch

In our monolith application that used **JHIPSTER-6.10.5**, we were using **Spring-Data-Elastic Version: 3.3.1** with **Elastic Search Version: 6.8.8**. We have multiple `@ManyToOne` and `@OneToMany` relationships with over a 100+ entities.
In some cases a maximum of 7 entities are referenced from each other (I mean interlinked not just from one to other).
For elastic searching, We have been using

1. To ignore indexing: `@JsonIgnoreProperities(value = { "unwanted fields" }, allowSetters = true)` and  `@JsonIgnore`  where not needed
2. To map the relations: on `ManyToOne`'s we use  `@JsonBackReference` with a corresponding `@JsonManagedReference` on the respective `OneToMany` relationships.

Now we are in process of migration to Jhipster-7.0.1 and started seing the below problems:

1. **New Spring-Data-Elastic Version: 4.1.6 with Elastic Search Version: 7.9.3**
2. Now with Spring data elastic, the Jackson based mapper is not available we are seeing multiple StackOverflow errors. Below is the migration change we did on the annotations:

   1. On the relationships we have added `@Field(type = FieldType.Nested, ignoreMalformed = true, ignoreFields = {"unwanted fields"})`. This stopped StackOverflow errors at Spring data level but still throw StackOverflow errors at elastic rest-client level internally. So, we are forced to use `@Transient` to exclude all the `OnetoMany` relations.
   2. Even on `ManyToOne` relations with the above mentioned `@Field` annotation present we are facing the elasticsearchexception with "Limit of total fields [1000] in index [] has been exceeded"
   3. I have tried to follow the documentation on [spring data](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#reference), but could not resolve it.
   4. We have kept the Json(Jackson) Annotations also that were generated by Jhipster but they have no effect.

We are stalled at the moment as we are not sure how to resolve these issues; personally it was very convenient and well documented to  use the Json annotations; We being new to both elastic search and spring data elastic search, started using it just for the past 8 months back, not able to figure out how to fix these errors.
Please ask if i missed any information needed. I will share as much as it doesn't voilate the org policies.

Sample code Repository as requested on gitter: https://gitlab.com/thelearner214/spring-data-es-sample

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach we are using as a stop gap arrangement until we rewrite / find a better solution. Can't use separate classes for ES, like [@P.J.Meisch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67558754/indexing-problem-with-spring-data-elastic-migration-from-3-x-to-4-x#comment119421940_67560840) advised, as we have large number of entities to maintain and a "microservice migration program" is already in progress.

Posting here as it might be useful for someone else with a similar issue.

Created a utility to serialize and deserialize the entity to get the benefit of Jackson annotations on the class. Ex: `@JsonIgnoreProperities`, `@JsonIgnore` etc.
This way, we are able to reduce usage of the `@Transient` annotation and still get the ID(s) of the related object(s).

```
package com.sample.shop.service.util;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.hibernate5.Hibernate5Module;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

public class ESUtils {

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ESUtils.class);

public static <T> Optional<T> mapForES(Class<T> type, T input) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = getObjectMapper();
    try {
        return Optional.ofNullable(mapper.readValue(mapper.writeValueAsString(input), type));
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        log.error("Parsing exception {} {}", e.getMessage());
        return Optional.empty();
    } 
}

public static <T> List<T> mapListForES(Class<T> type, List<T> input) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = getObjectMapper();
    try {
        JavaType javaType = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, type);
        String serialText = mapper.writeValueAsString(input);
        return mapper.readValue(serialText, javaType);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        log.error("Parsing exception {} {}", e.getMessage());
    } 
}

@NotNull
private static ObjectMapper getObjectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
    mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_SELF_REFERENCES_AS_NULL, true);
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    Hibernate5Module module = new Hibernate5Module();
    module.disable(Hibernate5Module.Feature.FORCE_LAZY_LOADING);
    module.enable(Hibernate5Module.Feature.SERIALIZE_IDENTIFIER_FOR_LAZY_NOT_LOADED_OBJECTS);
    module.enable(Hibernate5Module.Feature.USE_TRANSIENT_ANNOTATION);
    module.enable(Hibernate5Module.Feature.REPLACE_PERSISTENT_COLLECTIONS);
    return mapper;
    }
}
```

Then, to save a single entry, have adjusted the logic to save to use the above utility like:

```
//    categorySearchRepository.save(result); instead of the Jhipster generated code let's use the ESUtils
ESUtils.mapForES(Category.class,category).map(res -> categorySearchRepository.save(res));
```

And to save a list to for bulk-reindex, using the second utility:

```
Page<T> categoryPage = jpaRepository.findAll(page);
List<T> categoryList = ESUtils.mapListForES(Category.class, categoryPage.getContent());
elasticsearchRepository.saveAll(categoryList);
```

Might not be a best solution, but got the work done for our migration.

Comment: Hey, I'm getting "Missing return statement" for the mapListForEs ,
What should it return for the catch.
I'm new to java 

Comment: Here is a more general solution to the problem on official thread: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/16136#issuecomment-1012404392

Comment: @ConstantinZagorsky looks like the solution you propose is to create a converter for each domain type. However, as stated above 'we have large number of entities to maintain' so that solution doesn't work for our app. Hence we are using the above mentioned solution(still heavy to replace a single line in all the service classes) till the good guys at Jhipster provide a better solution...

Answer (score 4):

Had a look at the repository you linked on gitter (you might consider adding a link here).

First: the `@Field` annotation is used to write the index mapping and the `ignoreFields` property is needed to break circular references when the mapping is built. It is **not** used when the entity is written to Elasticsearch.

What happens for example with the `Address` and `Customer` entities during writing to Elasticsearch: The `Customer` document has `Address`es so these adresses are converted as subdocuments embedded in the `Customer` document. But the `Address` has a `Customer`, so on writing the address the `Customer` is embedded into this `Address` element which already is a subdocument of the customer.

I suppose the `Customer`s should not be stored in the `Address` and the other way round.  So you need to mark these embedded documents as `@org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient`, you don't need the `@Field` annotation on them as you don not want to store them as properties in the index.

Jackson annotations are not used by Spring Data Elasticsearch anymore.

The basic problem of the approach that is used here, is that the modelling that comes from a relational world - linking and joining different tables with (one|many)to{one|many) relationships, manifested in a Java object graph by an ORM mapper - is used on a document based data store that does not use these concepts.

It used to work in your previous version, because the elder version of Spring Data Elasticsearch used Jackson as well and so these fields were skipped on writing, now you have to add the `@Transient` annotation which is a Spring Data annotation.

But I don't know how `@Transient` might interfere with Spring Data JPA - another point that shows that it's not a good idea to use the same Java class for different stores

Comment: Thanks for the quick and detailed Response @P.J.Meish.  As I understand: As ``Customer`` already has ``Address`` subdocuments we need to mark ``Customer`` in the ``Address`` document should be marked @Transient. That may break the ORM mapping as you mentioned.  One more quick question, do you recommend to separate the ``Entity`` and ``Document`` classes and map/populate them separately before saving?

Comment: Also, are there any other annotation than ``@Transient`` available or planned for Spring Data Elastic alone without an impact to JPA. Asking, because the change of the project structures for version upgrade will result in significant time and budgets for existing projects.

Comment: I would always use different classes to store data in different stores. If you do this, there is no need to have additional annotations. What many people also do: They return the store entites directly over a REST API. And there Jackson will again interpret these annotations. Splitting these means more work, but you have a cleaner working setup with less danger of incompatible settings.

Answer (score 0):

[@Lina Basuni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10216293/lina-basuni) You can use `java.util.Collections.emptyList()`